# How can I make bash `set` only list environmental variables and not functions

Tags: linux, bash

I use the `set` bash command to list the environmental variables that are set on my system.  Nowadays the output of `set` is littered with hundreds of function definitions.  I rather wouldn't use `set | head` or something like that.

Ideally, I'd like `set` not to list any function definitions.  How can I make it behave like that?

Comment: cross site duplicate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3510/how-to-print-only-defined-variables-shell-and-or-environment-variables-in-bash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `env` command to list environment variables.

Comment: Beaten to the punch by 30 secs :P - delling my answer now ;-)

Comment: note that env only prints "exported" environment variables whereas set also prints the "not exported" shell variables. for more information see: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3507/difference-between-environment-variables-and-exported-environment-variables-in-b